# react redux async action call next function after finishing the function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Lets say I have a functin that calls api:

```
export default function AuthApi({url, method, headers, data}={}){
    return (dispatch, getState) => {

        fetch(url, {
            method: method || null,
            headers: headers || null,
            body: form || null,
            }).then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            }).then(function(response){
                console.log(response)
            })

    }
}
```

Now I want to call this api somewhere in action:

```
      dispatch(AuthApi({url: "some_url", method: "POST", data: data}))
      console.log("called api")
      dispatch(userInfo(response))
      console.log(getState())
      router.pushState(null, '/profile')
```

Here I am calling the api with `dispatch` and then `dispatch(userInfo)` .
I assume my `dispatch(userInfo())` function to be called after all the processing in `dispatch(AuthApi())`

But here it goes into `AuthApi()` but without completing it it start to call other function or process

How can I only call my other function or logic or ever `console.log()` after `dispatch(AuthApi())` is completely finished.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use Promises, they work perfectly well with `thunkMiddleware`:

```
dispatch(AuthApi({url: "some_url", method: "POST", data: data})).then((response) => {
    dispatch(userInfo(response))
})
```

[More examples here](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)

**UPDATE**
You should also modify action to return promise.

```
export default function AuthApi({url, method, headers, data}={}){
    return (dispatch, getState) => {    
        return fetch(url, {
            method: method || null,
            headers: headers || null,
            body: form || null,
        }).then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        })    
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to add `return` into action